# How to test-run jMonkey?

Tags: jmonkeyengine

I'm trying the basic jMonkey but I get this exception

```
jun 27, 2012 9:25:08 FM com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem initialize
Info: Running on jMonkeyEngine 3.0.0 Beta
jun 27, 2012 9:25:08 FM com.jme3.system.Natives extractNativeLibs
Info: Extraction Directory: C:\prv_workspace_8\DungeonWorldAdventure
jun 27, 2012 9:25:13 FM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay run
Info: Using LWJGL 2.8.3
jun 27, 2012 9:25:13 FM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglDisplay createContext
Info: Selected display mode: 640 x 480 x 0 @0Hz
jun 27, 2012 9:25:13 FM com.jme3.app.Application handleError
Allvarlig: Failed to create display
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:214)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:873)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:782)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglDisplay.createContext(LwjglDisplay.java:137)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:113)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

jun 27, 2012 9:25:13 FM com.jme3.app.Application handleError
Allvarlig: Uncaught exception thrown in Thread[LWJGL Renderer Thread,5,main]
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.runLoop(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:147)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglDisplay.runLoop(LwjglDisplay.java:182)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:223)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "LWJGL Renderer Thread"
```

The code I'm trying to run is

```
package adventure;

import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;
import com.jme3.material.Material;
import com.jme3.math.Vector3f;
import com.jme3.scene.Geometry;
import com.jme3.scene.shape.Box;
import com.jme3.math.ColorRGBA;

/** Sample 1 - how to get started with the most simple JME 3 application.
 * Display a blue 3D cube and view from all sides by
 * moving the mouse and pressing the WASD keys. */
public class Test extends SimpleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test app = new Test();
        app.start(); // start the game
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        Box b = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, 1, 1, 1); // create cube shape at the origin
        Geometry geom = new Geometry("Box", b);  // create cube geometry from the shape
        Material mat = new Material(assetManager,
          "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");  // create a simple material
        mat.setColor("Color", ColorRGBA.Blue);   // set color of material to blue
        geom.setMaterial(mat);                   // set the cube's material
        rootNode.attachChild(geom);              // make the cube appear in the scene
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a graphics card driver problem. Make sure to update your drivers. If that doesn't work, your graphics card just may be outdated.